# Adding Parameters to Serverless.Template File

Tags: aws-sam

I am using Jenkins Pipeline to publish a Visual Studio AWS Serverless .Net Core Application.

Can somebody tell me whether it is possible to add parameters to the serverless.template file? I would then be able to populate these parameters using the aws cli as part of the Jenkins build process.

For example if I wanted to publish to a staging environment with different VpcConfig values than the production environment;

```
"VpcConfig": {
        "SecurityGroupIds": [
            [PARAMETER_TO_BE_PASSED_IN_VIA_CLI]
        ],
        "SubnetIds": [
            [PARAMETER_TO_BE_PASSED_IN_VIA_CLI],
            [PARAMETER_TO_BE_PASSED_IN_VIA_CLI]
        ]
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, we can define `cloudfront` aliases for dev, staging, prod and specify them under `vpcConfig` section.

Please find below code snippet

```
cloudfront:
  aliases:
    dev:
      - Fn::Join:
        - ''
        - - app-
          - 'dev'-
          - { Ref: AWS::AccountId }
          - .yourwebsite.com
    staging:
      - Fn::Join:
        - ''
        - - app-
          - 'staging'-
          - { Ref: AWS::AccountId } 
          - .yourwebsite.com
    prod:
      - yourwebsite.com
      - www.yourwebsite.com
```

and then mention them under `vpcConfig` section.

```
vpcConfig:
  dev:
    ${file(PathToSystem/vpcConfig.yml)}
  staging:
    ${file(PathToSystem/vpcConfig.yml)}
  prod:
    ${file(PathToSystem/vpcConfig.yml)}
```